# Generating DataContext from database (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, datacontext

I've used once an downloadable add-on for entity framework, from the internet or Nu-Get to generate DAL with DataContext and all information by right clicking on the project and selecting "Generate.. From Database" and it creates a DataContext filled with all the information needed, including classes representing the data.

for some reason I cannt find it. does someone know what i mean and can give me a link for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Visual Studio Extension not a NuGet package.  In VS go to Tools -> Extension Manager and search for Context or POCO on the online Gallery.

Comment: When I do that i get message:
"A connection to the server could not be established because the following error occurred: The server has returned invalid data. Please try again later."

I've tried this:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/689766/visual-studio-extension-manager-online-gallery-error

but i didnt make it work

Comment: That's a networking issue either your end or as the article suggests possibly on Microsoft's side due to load.  FWIW the gallery is working fine for me at the time of writing.  Speak to your Network Admin to do some basic troubleshooting your side.  Failing that you might want to ask a different question on here or ServerFault as this issue isn't related to the original question.